# PHP merge arrays into 2D JSON

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I have 3 JSON strings coming in with POST and want to merge these into a 2 dimensional array and save in JSON format to the database.
For this example I have image URL's, alt descriptions and booleans isfavorite

```
$url_arr = json_decode('["http://site.com/001.jpg","http://site.com/003.jpg","http://site.com/002.jpg"]');
$alt_arr = json_decode('["testing internat chars àèéìòóù stop","second description",""]'); // UTF-8 supported
$isFav_arr = json_decode('["true", "false", "false"]'); // strings need to be converted to booleans

// merge into 2 dimensional array
// $img_arr = array_merge($url_arr, $alt_arr, $isFav_arr); // doesn't work, just add's to the end
// ...

// save 2D JSON in database
$to_db = json_encode($img_arr);
```

Comment: you want the three arrays to be in an array, right? and you want to save the JSON of that in the database, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just string concatenate:

```
$to_db = '[' 
       . '["http://site.com/001.jpg","http://site.com/003.jpg","http://site.com/002.jpg"]'
       . ',["testing int chars àèéìòóù stop","second description",""]'
       . ',["true", "false", "false"]'
       . ']';
```

Unless you want to work with the values in the Json string, you dont need any en/decoding.
You can use http://www.jsonlint.com/ to validate it (*removed jsonlint and `print_r` [dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4c01ba23-4417-4849-a82e-59170257febe/view-source) to make some space*)

Comment: mmm, yes I think so.. is this valid JSON? I mean I can json_decode() I need to be able to access for example 'alt for second image' ect.

Comment: I just tried echo print_r(json_decode($to_db)); but it returns 1?? Would it not be better something like [["001.jpg","descr 1",false],["002.jpg","descr 2",true]]

Comment: @FFish I am not sure I understand what you are asking. It is valid (after I added the missing commas) and if you want to shove the Json string to the DB then this should be the prefered way because decoding it is expensive.

Comment: OK, got it now (just copied your snipped, without the comma correction) That's great! thanks so much :-)

Answer (score 1):

$url_arr = json_decode('["http://site.com/001.jpg","http://site.com/003.jpg","http://site.com/002.jpg"]');
$alt_arr = json_decode('["testing int chars àèéìòóù stop","second description",""]'); // UTF-8 supported
$isFav_arr = json_decode('["true", "false", "false"]'); // strings need to be converted to booleans

$img_arr = array(
              "urls"=>$url_arr,
              "alts"=>$alts_arr,
              "favs"=>$isFav_arr
               );
$results = json_encode($img_arr);

// possibly you will need to clean up numeric indexes ... before building multydim array

Comment: this is also a good answer, but Gordon's solution saves json encoding as in my example I have them already encoded. cheers

Answer (score 0):

The easy bit:

```
$img_arr = array();

for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($url_arr); $i++) {
    $img_arr[] = array($url_arr[$i], $alt_arr[$i], $isFav_arr[$i]);
}
```

Saving to the DB depends which DB type you're using. Look at examples using either [`mysql_query`](https://www.php.net/mysql_query), or [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) (preferred).

Comment: escape running if you see a for loop with sizeof! long live precalculated array lenght