# PHP JSON decode - stdClass

Tags: php, json, stdclass

I was having a question about making a [2D JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078422/php-merge-arrays-into-2d-json)

Now I would like to know why I can't access the following:

```
$json_str = '{"urls":["http://example.com/001.jpg","http://example.com/003.jpg","http://example.com/002.jpg"],"alts":["testing int chars àèéìòóù stop","second description",""],"favs":["true", "false", "false"]}';

$j_string_decoded = json_decode($json_str);
// echo print_r($j_string_decoded); // OK

// test get url from second item
echo j_string_decoded['urls'][1];
// Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are accessing it with array-like syntax:

```
echo j_string_decoded['urls'][1];
```

Whereas object is returned.

Convert it to array by specifying second argument to `true`:

```
$j_string_decoded = json_decode($json_str, true);
```

Making it:

```
$json_str = '{"urls":["http://site.com/001.jpg","http://site.com/003.jpg","http://site.com/002.jpg"],"alts":["testing int chars àèéìòóù stop","second description",""],"favs":["true", "false", "false"]}';

$j_string_decoded = json_decode($json_str, true);
echo j_string_decoded['urls'][1];
```

Or Try this:

```
$j_string_decoded->urls[1]
```

Notice the `->` operator used for objects.

**Quoting from Docs:**

> Returns the value encoded in json in
>   appropriate PHP type. Values true,
>   false and null (case-insensitive) are
>   returned as TRUE, FALSE  and NULL
>   respectively. NULL is returned if the
>   json cannot be decoded or if the
>   encoded data is deeper than the
>   recursion limit.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 7):

`json_decode` by default turns JSON dictionaries into PHP objects, so you would access your value as `$j_string_decoded->urls[1]`

Or you could pass an additional argument as `json_decode($json_str,true)` to have it return associative arrays, which would then be compatible with `$j_string_decoded['urls'][1]`

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
json_decode($jsonstring, true);
```

to return an array.

Comment: Saved me! :vvvvvv

Comment: This should be answer too, change 2nd parameters from default false to true will solve PHP fatal error > illegal convert stdClass Object to Array