# How to traverse array after decoding JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP JSON decode - stdClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080755/php-json-decode-stdclass)

I have a **JSON** file with a structure like this:

```
[{"key_mappings": "",
  "screen2_thumb": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/screen2_thumb.png",
  "video_url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7MDxObgJxw",
  "rating": "Teen",
  "screen1_thumb": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/screen1_thumb.png",
  "metascore": 43.63,
  "height": 500,
  "screen3_thumb": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/screen3_thumb.jpg",
  "stage3d": false,
  "screen3_url": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/screen3.jpg", 
  "recommendation": 5,
  "coins_revshare_enabled": null,
  "category": "Fighting",
  "screen4_thumb": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/screen4_thumb.png",
  "uuid": "6789c7e3-fd27-345e-85d9-e6a58165ae57",
  "author": "Juice-Tin",
  "thumbnail_large_url": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/_thumb_200x200.png",
  "author_link": "https://www.mochimedia.com/community/profile/Juice-Tin",
  "controls":
    [["C", "Item"],
     ["V", "Spell"],
     ["X", "Heavy Attack"],
     ["Z", "Fast Attack"],
     ["fire", "na"],
     ["jump", "na"],
     ["movement", "arrow"]],
  "languages": ["en"],
  "swf_url": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/Siegius%20Arena_.swf",
  "recommended": true,
  "game_tag": "e0e05c5c5fd1a61b",
  "achievements_enabled": false,
  "zip_url": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena.zip",
  "screen1_url": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/screen1.png",
  "updated": "2012-10-25T15:47:01.953336-08:00",
  "description": "Fight in arena battles and upgrade your gladiator in this Action-RPG about betrayal and revenge.",
  "tags": ["siegius", "arena", "gladiator", "rome", "battle", "fight", "upgrade", "rpg", "fans", "en"],
  "swf_file_size": 10142842,
  "leaderboard_enabled": false,
  "game_url": "http://www.mochimedia.com/games/siegius-arena",
  "screen2_url": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/screen2.png",
  "slug": "siegius-arena",
  "categories": ["Action", "Fighting"],
  "instructions": "", 
  "name": "Siegius Arena",
  "created": "2012-10-25T12:47:55.080005-08:00",
  "control_scheme": "{\"C\": \"Item\", \"fire\": \"na\", \"jump\": \"na\", \"V\": \"Spell\", \"X\": \"Heavy Attack\", \"Z\": \"Fast Attack\", \"movement\": \"arrow\"}", 
  "popularity": 0,
  "feed_approval_created": "2012-10-25T13:30:53.505710-08:00",
  "coins_enabled": null,
  "thumbnail_url": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/_thumb_100x100.png",
  "screen4_url": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/screen4.png", 
  "alternate_url": "",
  "resolution": "800x500",
  "width": 800}]
```

Then, I have a foreach statement which adds the data to a MYSQL database:

```
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    if($value) { 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `games_db`.`Games` (`title`, `description`, `image`, `category`, `page`, `rating`, `width`, `height`, `tags`) VALUES ('$value->name', '$value->description', '/images/$pageid.jpg', '$category', '$pageid', '$value->rating', '$value->width', '$value->height', '$value->tags')")  
}
```

My question is, What do I have to do to show and insert the tags from the JSON file? Currently, When I run this page, the data for the "tags" column just says "Array".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) as so:

```
$jsonString = '[{"key_mappings": "", "screen2_thumb": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/screen2_thumb.png", "video_url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7MDxObgJxw", "rating": "Teen", "screen1_thumb": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/screen1_thumb.png", "metascore": 43.63, "height": 500, "screen3_thumb": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/screen3_thumb.jpg", "stage3d": false, "screen3_url": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/screen3.jpg", "recommendation": 5, "coins_revshare_enabled": null, "category": "Fighting", "screen4_thumb": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/screen4_thumb.png", "uuid": "6789c7e3-fd27-345e-85d9-e6a58165ae57", "author": "Juice-Tin", "thumbnail_large_url": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/_thumb_200x200.png", "author_link": "https://www.mochimedia.com/community/profile/Juice-Tin", "controls": [["C", "Item"], ["V", "Spell"], ["X", "Heavy Attack"], ["Z", "Fast Attack"], ["fire", "na"], ["jump", "na"], ["movement", "arrow"]], "languages": ["en"], "swf_url": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/Siegius%20Arena_.swf", "recommended": true, "game_tag": "e0e05c5c5fd1a61b", "achievements_enabled": false, "zip_url": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena.zip", "screen1_url": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/screen1.png", "updated": "2012-10-25T15:47:01.953336-08:00", "description": "Fight in arena battles and upgrade your gladiator in this Action-RPG about betrayal and revenge.", "tags": ["siegius", "arena", "gladiator", "rome", "battle", "fight", "upgrade", "rpg", "fans", "en"], "swf_file_size": 10142842, "leaderboard_enabled": false, "game_url": "http://www.mochimedia.com/games/siegius-arena", "screen2_url": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/screen2.png", "slug": "siegius-arena", "categories": ["Action", "Fighting"], "instructions": "", "name": "Siegius Arena", "created": "2012-10-25T12:47:55.080005-08:00", "control_scheme": "{\"C\": \"Item\", \"fire\": \"na\", \"jump\": \"na\", \"V\": \"Spell\", \"X\": \"Heavy Attack\", \"Z\": \"Fast Attack\", \"movement\": \"arrow\"}", "popularity": 0, "feed_approval_created": "2012-10-25T13:30:53.505710-08:00", "coins_enabled": null, "thumbnail_url": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/_thumb_100x100.png", "screen4_url": "http://games.mochiads.com/c/g/siegius-arena/screen4.png", "alternate_url": "", "resolution": "800x500", "width": 800}]';
$jsonObject = json_decode($jsonString);
foreach ($jsonObject->tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag . PHP_EOL;
    //Do something
}
```

If you use less than PHP 5.2.0, you can use the [JSON PECL Extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/json)

I should also add that you **shouldn't** use the `mysql` functions any more - they're deprecated. See: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

> json_decode — Decodes a JSON string

```
$jsonObject = json_decode($string);   // returns an object
```

or:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($string, true);  // if second argument is true, returned object will be converted to an associative array
```

Edit:

as suggested by @nickhar: NOTE: You need PHP 5.2.0 or above to use json_decode()

Or [one of the emulations floating around](http://include-once.org/p/upgradephp) – @mario

Comment: NOTE: You need PHP 5.2.0 or above to use `json_decode()`

Comment: @nickhar Or one of the emulations floating around, http://include-once.org/p/upgradephp/